# Error near GO from C# to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Following query when executed from c# throws exception:

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE dbo.GENTBLDOCUMENT SET fTitle = temp.Title FROM dbo.GENTBLDOCUMENT T INNER JOIN #TmpTable Temp ON  " +
                        "(T.fDocumentId = Temp.DocumentId); DROP TABLE #TmpTable;" + Environment.NewLine + "GO ";
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.

However when I copy from text visualizer and run in ssms it runs fine.At the same time if I remove  following chunk of code it runs fine:

```
 + Environment.NewLine + "GO "
```

Thanks for looking into this. I am using Temp table here with bulkcopying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`GO` is only used in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-2017) (e.g. in SQL Management Studio) to tell the server to execute the previous commands.

It's not valid SQL and cannot be used in queries. Simply remove it from your `CommandText`. The query will be executed without it.

Answer (score 0):

GO marks the "batch" in a script to run. You wouldn't have that in your script called from C#. You would also want to write the script as verbatim for better readability:

```
command.CommandText = @"UPDATE dbo.GENTBLDOCUMENT 
        set fTitle = temp.Title 
    from dbo.GENTBLDOCUMENT T 
    INNER JOIN #TmpTable Temp 
      ON T.fDocumentId=Temp.DocumentId; 
    DROP TABLE #TmpTable;
";
```

Note: As per "bulk copying" you might want to use SqlBulkCopy class.